Annotations on QGIS map in Python
I would like to use the create a text annotation at point tool on QGIS from a python code. The goal is to use it in a plugin I'm creating so that the user can display text on the map.
The problem is that I don't know which functions to use. I've tried QgsTextAnnotation but it creates a simple text annotation and not a text annotation at point.
I found this function: QgsAnnotationPointTextItem. I managed to create the object, but now I don't know how to get it to display on my map.
How can I make this annotation appear on the QGIS map?
        # Créer une annotation textuelle au point spécifié
        texte_annotation = QgsAnnotationPointTextItem("test", QgsPointXY(self.coord.x(), self.coord.y()))
        
        # Définir le format du texte
        text_format = QgsTextFormat()
        text_format.setColor(QColor(255, 0, 0))  # Couleur rouge
        text_format.setSize(12)  # Définir la taille de la police
        text_format.setBuffer(QgsTextBufferSettings())
        
        # Appliquer le format de texte à l'annotation
        texte_annotation.setFormat(text_format)
        
        # Définir l'angle de rotation du texte
        texte_annotation.setAngle(orientation)


For adding your item to map, you need to get access to annotation layer of your project (or create your own).
Easy way:
add after your code
an_layer = QgsProject.instance().mainAnnotationLayer()
an_layer.addItem(texte_annotation)

